# Opencart place order without checkout payment through email

Tags: opencart-3

In opencart, I want to place an order without a payment method. But if my order reaches upto specific limit for each product I want to send an automatic email to all the customers for payment through a link when they click on the link I want to redirect them to the payment gateway which I am using Is this possible Can you provide me the step how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

I just want to know if this is possible in opencart without any extension or not